# How to read values from a file alternating variables?

Tags: java, arrays, file, int

How can I use Scanner to read from a .txt with the first value going to a int x, the second value go to int y, third go to int x and go on..
And doing validation.
I wrote my code like this but it doesn't read all values:

```
Scanner kb = new Scanner(f);
while(kb.hasNextInt())
    {
        k[n] = new Medida();
        tmp = kb.nextInt();
        if(tmp >= 0 && tmp <= 100)
        k[n].hum = tmp;
        tmp1 = kb.nextInt();
        if(tmp1 >= -10 && tmp1 <= 40)
        k[n].temp = tmp1;
        n++;
        if(n == 31) break;                                                                                           
    }
```

My file is like this:

- 12 -> int x
- 1 -> int y
- 12 -> int x
- 3 -> int y
- 13 -> int x
- 14 -> int y
- 11 -> int x

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "doesn't read all the values"? Which and how many values exactly are missing? The first? The last? Some in between?

Comment: I think more than half of them. In all positions..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert file to List (Java 7):

```
List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

after, run in loop on list and split line by `->`

```
    final String SPLIT = "-> int ";

    List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("C:\\test.txt"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    int x = 0,y = 0;

    int temp;

    for(int i=0; i<lines.size(); i++){

        temp = Integer.parseInt(lines.get(i).split(SPLIT)[0].trim());
        // in case id line contains integer only:
        // temp = Integer.parseInt(lines.get(i).trim());

        if(i % 2 == 0){
            x += temp;
        }
        else{
            y += temp;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(x);
    System.out.println(y);
```

Comment: well I didn't learned how to work with List. Is there anyway I can do it?

Comment: @Max I don't think his file contains the "-> int", he was just showing how he wants the int allocated.

Comment: @Jurgen maybe but the concept stays the same, run per line and check `i % 2`

Comment: Yes the -> was just a reference.

Comment: @Maxim now I get it. I can do it the way I was doing it but just using the: if(i % 2 == 0). thanks for your help!